# How to distinguish different sources of spontaneous QCloseEvent in Qt5?

Tags: qt

in my application, I override `QMainWindow::closeEvent` in order to do some logic before closing the app.
The only argument this function gets is of type `QCloseEvent`, and it's called whenever the user tries to close the app.
It happens when we click the X button, of course, but depending on platform we also have things like `alt+f4`, `rightclick->close` and possibly more.

My goal here is to distinguish between these. More specifically, I need to know if just the X button was pressed or not.

From to the docs, which can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcloseevent-members.html
I can't see anything that would help me get this information.
There is a function `spontaneous()`, which allows me to check if the event was triggered programmatically or by the environment/user, but in the case I'm presenting, every event has this value as `true`.

Unfortunately, I don't even know if this is possible.
I expect that it could work in a way that X11 or some other component in the system would just send the same signal for every case, but I don't really know where to look for this information.

Other questions that I've found on stack cover the spontaneous vs non-spontaneous cases, thus the didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

`closeEvent()` is called after the **window** is closed, not necessarily when the application is closed. Therefore, it's not called until after all the logic for the key is processed.

Override `keyEvent()` and use that function to run your key press logic.

[Documentation here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html)